# Short story about child in a simulation and a pumpkin

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Pretty sure this was a short story. There is a child who likes riding his bicycle around town. One day (for halloween) his mother asks him to go buy a Pumpkin, and he rides out of town and buys a Pumpkin. He wasn't normally allowed to do this but he got distracted.

When he gets back home, the pumpkin is opened and is empty. The "parents" tell the child the truth, he is living in a simulation (and the parents are one too) and he is the last child on earth.

Comment: Is this the same story? https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/226583/82909

Comment: Is the child actually in the pumpkin?

Comment: I feel like words or whole sentences were left out of this. The child is in a "simulation pumpkin"? What is a "simulation pumpkin"? How does getting distracted lead to him being allowed to do something he's not normally allowed to do? Was there something that was supposed to be in the pumpkin, apart from pumpkin innards?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it means "The child is in a simulation. There's a pumpkin."

Comment: Yeah, my bad about the title. It appears I left out a word. @Luarel That seems very much like it, though there sadly doesn't seem like there is an answer.

Comment: Edited the title for you.